# Multiprocessing in python using queue of dictionary elements as input

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using following code to run a function in using multiprocessing in python:

The input is a queue of dictionary elements.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import Process

def get_bio(urllink):
    r=requests.get(urllink)
    data=r.text
    soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
    a=soup.body.get_text()
    return a


q=Queue()  #contains dictionary elements. Ex:{'abc':['google.com','w3.org']}

for authr,urls in q.get().items():
    for url in urls:
        processes = [mp.Process(target=get_bio,args=(url,))]
for proc in processes:
    proc.start()
for proc in processes:
    proc.join()
```

the code prints the output only for the first dictionary element but do not continue to the next element in the queue. Can someone tell me where I am wrong? Is the snippet of code for multiprocessing correct?

Comment: This actually only prints the _last_ dictionary element, not the first. But, since dictionaries have arbitrary ordering before Python 3.7, it may be hard to tell the difference just by looking…

Answer (score 0):

Your code creates a new list `processes = [mp.Process(target=get_bio,args=(url,))]` for each `url` for each element in the queue, throwing away everything that was added from the previous element.

So, in the end, you just have a list of one process, created for the last URL of the last queue element. When you loop over `processes` twice, starting all of the processes, then joining them, you're just running that one last process. All of the others just get garbage collected without ever running.

What you probably wanted is something like this:

What you wanted may be something like this:

```
processes = []
for authr,urls in q.get().items():
    for url in urls:
        processes.append(mp.Process(target=get_bio,args=(url,))
for proc in processes:
    proc.start()
for proc in processes:
    proc.join()
```

Or maybe you wanted this:

```
for authr,urls in q.get().items():
    processes = []
    for url in urls:
        processes.append(mp.Process(target=get_bio,args=(url,))
    for proc in processes:
        proc.start()
    for proc in processes:
        proc.join()
```

Or maybe this:

```
allprocesses = []
for authr,urls in q.get().items():
    newprocesses = []
    for url in urls:
        newprocesses.append(mp.Process(target=get_bio,args=(url,))
    for proc in newprocesses:
        proc.start()
    allprocesses.extend(newprocesses)
for proc in allprocesses:
    proc.join()
```

It's hard to guess without knowing who's feeding that queue and, more generally, what you're trying to do with it.

But regardless, you definitely want to start and join *all* of your processes, for all of your urls for all of your queue elements, not just one. And if *you* know what you want, it should be easy for you to decide which one of these (or something different) will do what you want.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I have a file that contains author names along with their list of urls. So i have added them to queue using queue.put(dict). So each element in queue is dict of author_name and their urls. Each author may contain more than one url. I need a process to be assigned to each author to process his urls, while other processes to pick other authr and do the same.

Comment: @user7238503 Fine, but do you want to wait on all of the elements to be added to the queue before running any child processes, or are they going to be coming in gradually over time, so you want to kick off each process as soon as something comes over the queue?

Comment: I would like to start each process as soon as they come over the queue.

Comment: can you please help me with this :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51622213/python-multiprocessing-process-mixing-output